# Cannot build GCC against Musl. Error during installation on 'install-c++tools' step

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, musl

I need to build a **GCC** and all necessary libraries (**libc**, **libstdc++**, etc.) against the **Musl** library. I'd been trying to build version **13** and the **stable** one (on **10.07.2023**). **Musl** version **1.2.4** had been chosen. My final configuration of builds is

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-musl --target=x86_64-linux-musl --with-sysroot=/usr/local/musl --with-newlib --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --disable-multilib --enable-bootstrap
```

Compilation (**make all-gcc -j4**) was successful and without any errors every time. But during the installation (**sudo make install**) every time I saw this:

```
/bin/sh: line 4: cd: ./c++tools: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:15533: install-c++tools] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/***/Tools/gcc-musl-13/build'
make: *** [Makefile:2624: install] Error 2
```

Also I had been trying to configure and build it from an original directory with source code, not just from created subdirectory called **build** with different parameters.

What can cause this problem?